# to move a Gradient radius depending on ios device position/movemeant

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, radial-gradients

I'm developing a hybrid app and wondering if this scenario is feasible.

I don't know the word for this... Imagine a Fulcrum, the middle of the device is on top of it. The top part of the device moves up or down, the lower part of the device moves opposite.

My question is: Is there a way to detect these changes, and move a circular gradient radius depending on  which movement it of the device it is.

Perhaps this is possible using CSS instead of JS?

And how do I use the canvas to update the change in real time? Expensive to run?

Comment: You'd need to include the accelerometer plugin, and then do calculations based on that.  This would require plenty of JS to do, and the question itself is much, much too broad for Stack Overflow.  I recommend you start developing it yourself, and then ask questions where you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I might just try an do that :)